# Migrate WSE 2.0 web services from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, soap, wse

Just wondering if it is possible to migrate WSE 2.0 web services (.asmx) from a Windows 2003 server to a Windows 2008 R2 server (IIS 7)?  A further complication is that the services uses x509 certificates for security purposes.

I have copied the services from a Windows 2003 server onto the Windows 2008 R2 server, created them as web applications through IIS 7, and they show up in their URLs just fine.  However when I call the services via SOAP I get SOAP header exceptions:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: 
SOAP header Security was not understood.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderHandling.SetHeaderMembers(
SoapHeaderCollection headers, Object target, SoapHeaderMapping[] mappings, 
SoapHeaderDirection direction, Boolean 
client)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
at Microsoft.Web.Services2.Messaging.SoapClient.SendRequestResponse(
String methodname, SoapEnvelope envelope)
at RawSoapCaller.RawSoapCall.getRawSoapResponseText() in 
C:\Data\ISHS\metadata_framework\RawSoapCaller\RawSoapCaller\RawSoapCall.cs:line 59
```

Can anyone help me figure out if what I am doing is possible, and if so, what might be my problem here?  Or what alternative approaches I might take to migrate the WSE 2.0 services from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008?

Comment: I'm not sure WSE 2.0 is supported anymore. You should at least consider upgrading to WSE 3.0, which is obsolete, but still (barely) supported.

Comment: You're right, it's not supported.  But that doesn't mean that it won't work necessarily, just that Microsoft are not patching it or documenting fixes, right?

Comment: Also that there is a decreasing number of people in the world who either know about it, or who will admit to knowing about it. This means you are more likely to be on you own when you need help. Also, many organizations do not permit unsupported software to be used in Production. Why not at least upgrade to something obsolete and still supported for a little while longer, if you can't upgrade to something that's not obsolete?

Comment: Thanks John.  An adventurous rewrite of the code as a Java RESTful web service using JBoss AS and Google protocol buffers is currently under way!  The .NET 2.0 /WSE 2.0 web services at present are SOAP-based, time-consuming to manage (always hated WSDLs), and a bit slow... have decided to avoid as much XML hell as possible and take advantage of EJB annotations instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't properly transferred your certificates.

Try here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824840.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding a <x509> tag into the <security> part of web.config for a service to test it, and I still get the errors.  Would the <x509> tag conflict with the <securityTokenManager> by any chance?  My web.config looks like this:

    <security>
   <securityTokenManager ... />
   <x509 storeLocation="CurrentUser" />
  </security>

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: the certificate needs to be available in the machines cert store.

Comment: Hi Chris.  I did have the certificate in the machine's cert store... only WSE 2.0 was not able to see the "Personal" key store for some reason, even though it could be seen through MMC Certificates snap-in.  Weird.